# Taking information from mixed string and table file

Tags: r, file, text, read.table

I have text files. It contains header of string information and table of information.

```
info_in_file <- read.table( "ch4_alt_surface-flask_2_3001-9999_monthly.txt")
info_in_file
    V1   V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7   V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13     V14      V15 V16
1   ALT 1985  6  1  0  0  0 -999 -9  -9  -9  -9  -9 1728.52 -999.999  -9
2   ALT 1985  7  1  0  0  0 -999 -9  -9  -9  -9  -9 1716.95 -999.999  -9
3   ALT 1985  8  1  0  0  0 -999 -9  -9  -9  -9  -9 1715.50 -999.999  -9
4   ALT 1985  9  1  0  0  0 -999 -9  -9  -9  -9  -9 1739.49 -999.999  -9
5   ALT 1985 10  1  0  0  0 -999 -9  -9  -9  -9  -9 1760.60 -999.999  -9
```

But when I open this file in excel I find some strings. For example

```
site_name: Alert
```

I need to get some of this information. I need to get name of of station in variable. How should I solve my problem?
[This is that File](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2mxq/4R5vDDcSU)

Comment: *read.table* has `comment.char = "#"` argument, which ignores all the "header" rows.

Answer (score 0):

*read.table* has `comment.char = "#"` argument, which ignores all the "header" rows.

Use *readLines*, then *grep*

```
# read the data, as you did already
info_in_file <- read.table("ch4_alt_surface-flask_2_3001-9999_monthly.txt")

# read every row as a string
header <- readLines("ch4_alt_surface-flask_2_3001-9999_monthly.txt")

# extract the rows we need
header[ grepl("site_name", header) ]
```